# Shopware6 : How to create rules for custom field in order

Tags: shopware, shopware6, shopware6-app

My goal is to achieve something like the following with flowbuilder:

Trigger: order placed (achievable with the flowbuilder)

If : if order.customFields.customtextField not empty (trying to implement this)

Action : send email with (achievable with the flowbuilder)

For this, I am trying to add a custom rule for order following this : https://developer.shopware.com/docs/guides/plugins/plugins/framework/rule/add-custom-rules#create-custom-rule

But, I see that the last created order is not easily accessible in the rule class. Is there a better/recommended way to do check for an order custom field after order is placed?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Within the flow the order is converted back to a cart with the order line items becoming cart line items once again. This is done to make existing rules work for both evaluating carts and orders. This also means the custom fields of a placed order are not available in the context of the cart as they wouldn't be available yet during checkout. Unfortunately within a rule condition there is no ideal way to identify if the cart was converted from an existing order, no less which order it is.

What you could do however is [add a new flow action](https://developer.shopware.com/docs/guides/plugins/plugins/framework/flow/add-flow-builder-action). Within the scope of the action you could have access to the `order` entity and then decide within the action what to do with it. The triggers for order placed or enter/leave states will dispatch [`CheckoutOrderPlacedEvent`](https://github.com/shopware/platform/blob/7185a760cf63bc39632ff2c4a336d696b4d370ea/src/Core/Checkout/Cart/Event/CheckoutOrderPlacedEvent.php#L46) or [`OrderStateMachineStateChangeEvent`](https://github.com/shopware/platform/blob/78130165af46adecd730f386b88511840e619491/src/Core/Checkout/Order/Event/OrderStateMachineStateChangeEvent.php#L48) respectively. Both of these have a getter for the `order` entity which you will be able to access from within your action.

```php
public function handle(FlowEvent $event): void
{
    $baseEvent = $event->getEvent();
    if (!$baseEvent instanceof CheckoutOrderPlacedEvent && !$baseEvent instanceof OrderStateMachineStateChangeEvent) {
        return;
    }

    $order = $baseEvent->getOrder();
    // evaluate the order and decide what to do with it
}
```

Comment: Thanks. I see that this works. Also, in my case, I tried creating a new custom trigger (event) that is fired if order has a custom field that I am looking for.

Answer (score 0):

I see that another approach that worked for me was with adding a [custom trigger(event)](https://developer.shopware.com/docs/guides/plugins/plugins/framework/flow/add-flow-builder-trigger#create-a-new-trigger-event) which is dispatched when `checkout.order.placed` event is fired and if that event's `order` has the custom field that I am looking for.